# linq query to fetch employee details when any character is typed in textbox

Tags: linq

i am having one employee table which contain records like this:

empid   empname   city       salary
1        abc       hhh        1000

2        pqr       jnj         2000

3        qry       hhh         3000

i am having one textbox in which when i type **a** in small letter or capital letter then i want to display all details of employee in gridview whose name starts with a.

if i type **ab** then i should display employee records whose name starts with **ab**

means i want facebook like advance search facility.

right now my query is like this:

var query=from s in context.empdetails select s

can anyone provide me linq query for this?

Comment: Is it a web or desktop app? Wire up the text box for auto search is bit extra work. If you're looking for Linq to just fetch the name then use like ...var query=from s in context.empdetails select s.empname

Comment: it is web application

Comment: What Programming Language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
List<employees> employees = employess.Where(x=>x.empname.StartsWith(TextBoxName.Text)
                                     .ToList();
```

In order to work this you have to define the `TextChanged` event for your `TextBox`. That is

```
<TextBox ID=".." runat="server" .... TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
```

Then in the code behind class you will declare the corresponding event handler:

```
protected void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
{
    List<employees> employees = allEmployees.Where(x=>x.empname.StartsWith(TextBoxName.Text)
                                         .ToList();

    // Then you would bind the result to your grid/table the way you binded initially.
}
```

**NOTE** I suppose you have a way to get all the employess. Otherwise how you bind them to your table. In the provided solution I use the allEmployees collection, where contains all your employees. You have to change it correspondingly, since I can't draw from your post how you get the employees.

Comment: thank u so so so much for ur kind help.thank u so much once again.

Comment: @user3459997 you welcome ! I am glad that my answer helped you.